# Django CustomUser Signup attribute error: 'str' object has no attribute 'META'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the following error when I try to signup to my application:

```
AttributeError at /signup/: 'str' object has no attribute 'META'
```

**Complete Traceback:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/

Django Version: 3.0.5
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
 'widget_tweaks']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/atakancavuslu/Documents/DjangoProject/projectx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/atakancavuslu/Documents/DjangoProject/projectx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/atakancavuslu/Documents/DjangoProject/projectx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/atakancavuslu/Documents/DjangoProject/projectx/projectx/accounts/views.py", line 15, in signup
    return redirect('accounts:redirect')
  File "/Users/atakancavuslu/Documents/DjangoProject/projectx/projectx/accounts/views.py", line 7, in redirect
    return render(request, 'accounts/redirect.html')
  File "/Users/atakancavuslu/Documents/DjangoProject/projectx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/atakancavuslu/Documents/DjangoProject/projectx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/Users/atakancavuslu/Documents/DjangoProject/projectx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/atakancavuslu/Documents/DjangoProject/projectx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 169, in render
    with context.bind_template(self):
  File "/Users/atakancavuslu/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/atakancavuslu/Documents/DjangoProject/projectx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 246, in bind_template
    updates.update(processor(self.request))
  File "/Users/atakancavuslu/Documents/DjangoProject/projectx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/context_processors.py", line 40, in debug
    if settings.DEBUG and request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR') in settings.INTERNAL_IPS:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /signup/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'META'
```

Whatever I did, I couldn't resolve the error.

This is the SignUp view (I redirect to a "redirect" view after successful signup, this is here only for being placeholder, printing the logged in users email in a template)

**views.py**

```
def redirect(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/redirect.html')

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('accounts:redirect')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

I have a CustomUser object as my Authentication User model in my Django application. I use CustomUserCreationForm, and SignUpForm which inherits this CustomUserCreation Form (You can see below the CustomUser model, CustomManager as well as the CustomForms.)

**models.py**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField('email adress', unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_exhibitor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
```

**managers.py**

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The email must be set')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email',)


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email',)

class SignUpForm(CustomUserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
            model = CustomUser
            fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

Comment: Can you add complete error traceback?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I added the error traceback to the post.

Comment: What I understand is that somehow "request" is handled as a string, instead of request object here. But still cannot find the underlying cause and any solution.

Comment: Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61529532/12578202) answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have a view function named **`redirect(request)`** which is conflicting with Django's [**`redirect()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) function. So, change your view name to something else,

```
def redirect_view_function(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/redirect.html')
```